# cpp check complains dangerous use of c_str(). the value returned by c_str() is invalid after this call , how to solve this?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
if(ini_getstr(getname("hello"))) //this is the getname function call

char* ini_getstr(char * key) { //some code }

char* getname(std::string name) //need to return char* 
{ 
   std::string ininame("name"); 
   ininame.append(":"+name); 
   return (*char)ininame.c_str();//cpp check complains dangerous use of c_str().
}
```

Comment: `(*char)` should be a syntax error, `(char*)` is a cast.

Answer (score 3):

Your function won't work correctly, because it is returning a pointer to data stored inside the `ininame` object, but since `ininame` is a local variable, it gets destroyed when the function returns, leaving the calling code holding a pointer to data that is no longer valid.

The proper way to do what you want is just to return a std::string instead:

```
std::string getname(std::string name)
{
   std::string ininame("name");
   ininame.append(":"+name);
   return ininame;
}
```

... and then your calling code can call c_str() on the returned object, if it needs to:

```
std::string myStr = getname("blah");
printf("The string was %s\n", myStr.c_str());
```

Answer (score 2):

The std::string owns the memory allocated for the string. So looking here:

```cpp
char* getname(std::string name) 
{ 
   std::string ininame("name"); 
   ininame.append(":"+name); 
   // ininame is a temporary variable that exists within the scope of this method.
   // once the return has been completed, ininame (and the memory it owns) will 
   // be destroyed. So whilst the pointer is valid when c_str() is called here,
   // the memory it's pointing to will be deleted as soon as return has completed.
   // this isn't safe!
   return (*char)ininame.c_str();
}
```

You'd be better off just returning the string (since the string object will not delete the memory)

```cpp
std::string getname(std::string name)
{ 
   std::string ininame("name"); 
   ininame.append(":"+name); 
   return ininame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strdup` function if you can't change the `getName` function signature.
`strdup` returns a pointer to a null-terminated byte string, which is a duplicate of the string pointed to.

```
char* getname(std::string name) //need to return char* 
{ 
  std::string ininame("name"); 
  ininame.append(":"+name); 
  return strdup(ininame.c_str());//cpp check complains dangerous use of c_str().
}
```

But remember

> The returned pointer must be passed to free to avoid a memory leak.